# Need a font size with fraction in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text

I bought the book on Inkscape and searched this site. I set preferences in Inkscape to points for text-unit-type.

For running a decorative calligraphy-text in a loop once around a page (along a path) and make the ends fit nicely I would need exactly 11.35 point font size. But Inkscape only lets me select 11pt or 12pt, not a fraction (like Scribus allows). I tried "." and "," for the fraction-delimiter but neither works.

I have tweaked the "spacing between letters" option, but that makes our text very ugly, so I would love to adjust the font-size instead.

Is this possible? And what is the hack please?

I am working on Inkscape 64bit 0.91 r13725 under Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: Entering a font size with decimals is supported in Inkscape. There is no secret trick, you only type the number you want into the field.

Comment: Thank you Moinilein for this encouragement. Now it just remains the follow-up question: How do you do it? I told about my version above. I am using computers for some 40 years and normally I manage to type the right thing into a box and get results. If you would want 11.35 pt size, what would you type? 11.35 and 11,35 do not work for me. Do I need to type the unit as well? Any more detail would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have missed selecting all text.

1. Select the text object with the arrow tool
2. Switch to the text tool
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all text
4. In the toolbar, adjust the font size, type `11.35` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Inscape Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you Thomas, that is so helpful. I was surprised and it works, exactly what we need. Then I tried with a "normal" text, just selecting it with the text tool: I can change the font size (even assign fractions like 11.35) without selecting any character; and it will still change the size of the entire text (a little bit similar as in Scribus). So it was the need to select the entire text that I had missed in case of this "along a path". All thumbs up.